# CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node when trying to connect to ropsten

Tags: solidity, metamask, ropsten, connections

I have Metamask installed on chrome and am connected to the Ropsten test network through there. However, whenever I try running my Javascript, I get the following error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node. When I was running my code on testrpc, it was working fine, but it doesn't work when I try to connect to ropsten.

Javascript:

```
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
    console.log('metamask');
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

}

else{
    console.log('something else');
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var betContractInstance = web3.eth.contract([MY ABI]);
var betContract = betContractInstance.at('0xed5ae2f841ce23cfe6ea9e39984e66afbf445143');
```

testing.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Testing{
    address [] public adds;
    uint [] public amounts;

    function bet() public payable {
        adds.push(msg.sender);
        amounts.push(msg.value);
    }

    function give() public {
        adds[0].transfer(amounts[0]);
    }
}
```

The error arrises at `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];`. I tried making `web3` global but that didn't help either. Does anybody know how I can fix this? I've seen this question asked before but most of them use geth instead of metamask. Also, the setup of my project is based on [this tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)), so I'm not sure of there's anyother dependecies I need.

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: the output to the console is "something else", so I'm assuming it's not detecting the Web3 injected by metamask.

Answer (score 0):

Define web3 detection after `load` event was fired at the page to get `web3` object, as it is suggested in [MetMask detection guide](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md#detecting-metamask):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   //read web3 object here
})
```